# Trigger event when row is selected in a Kendo UI Grid (Angular 2)

Tags: events, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

In Kendo UI (beta) for Angular 2, how does one trigger an event when a specific row is selected? There are no directives or components for the rows themselves; therefore, a (click)="triggeredFunction()" can't work if there is no row element.

**Here is my grid:**

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [selectable]="true">

  <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName">
    <template kendoHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
     {{column.field}}({{columnIndex}})
    </template>
  </kendo-grid-column>     

  <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName">
    <template kendoCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="listItems"></kendo-dropdownlist>
    </template>
  </kendo-grid-column>

</kendo-grid>
```

**Here is my component:**

```
@Component({
 selector: "ultron",
 styleUrls: [String("./ultron.component.less")],
 templateUrl: "./ultron.component.html",
 })
 export class UltronComponent {

   private gridData: any[] = [{
      "ProductID": 1,
      "ProductName": "Chai",
      "UnitPrice": 18.0000,
      "Discontinued": true,
    }, {
      "ProductID": 2,
      "ProductName": "Chang",
      "UnitPrice": 19.0000,
      "Discontinued": false,
    }
  }];

  private listItems: Array<string> = ["@", "$", "#", "%"];

  public triggeredFunction(){ ... }

}
```

Comment: Try `[selectable]="'row'"` http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-selectable

Comment: @DanWilson, Thanks for the quick response. The link you sent me is for Angular 1 (I need Angular 2). So.. I placed my function in the the spot you mentioned [selectable]="triggeredFunction()", which will trigger every time something changes on the page, and also when you click a row, but how do you pass the specific row data to the component?

Comment: I think you need to specify `'row'` as the selectable component and provide a `(change)` handler, which would be your `triggeredFunction()`. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/events

Comment: @DanWilson. Thanks again for responding. I changed it to `[selectable]="'row'"`, and created a handler for `(change)` but nothing happens. I am not sure if I'm placing the handler in the wrong spot, where is it supposed to be placed? Also you keep sending links to Angular 1 documentation, which does not apply to Angular 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The option that you need to set is `selectable` and the valid values are `true` and `false` as currently only single row selection is supported. So your grid should look like this

```
<kendo-grid
      [data]="gridView"
      [selectable]="true"
    >
  </kendo-grid>
```

For the event you need to attach a `(selectionChange)` event handler. Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xEB6JN9ZVjm499G2KreX?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Works like a charm. Is it possible to pass in the selected row element or the row data as well? I tried the $event and but it only gives me the index.  With `KendoCellsTemplates` you can use `let-dataItem` to get the row data, is there something we can use for the whole row selected?

Comment: `$event` will give you the index of the selected item and then you can get it from the data array - here http://plnkr.co/edit/xEB6JN9ZVjm499G2KreX?p=preview

Comment: @knikolov The index keeps changing when we do a sorting, So then when we try to look for the data with that index, it will show the wrong data. Do you have any other solution.

Comment: You can retrieve row data like this: public onSelect(e) {
        // e.selectedRows[0].dataItem.Id }

Comment: Do we have any page where all the available events for angular kendo grid 2 is available

Answer (score 4):

Selection in a Kendo UI enabled through the selectable option. The selected row index and selected state are provided through the selectionChange event. If you are also sorting or paging data in the grid then you will be bound to a GridDataResult. To get the bound item of the selected row in the grid, use the data property of the GridDataResult. See the following code sample:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GridDataResult, SelectionEvent } from "@progress/kendo-angular-grid";
import { SortDescriptor, orderBy } from "@progress/kendo-data-query";


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <kendo-grid [data]="gridDataResult" [selectable]="true" [height]="500" 
                [sortable]="true" (selectionChange)="selectedRowChange($event)" 
                [sort]="sort" (sortChange)="sortChange($event)">
                <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" [width]="300"></kendo-grid-column>
                <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name"></kendo-grid-column>
                <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="UnitPrice"></kendo-grid-column>
                <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" title="Discontinued"></kendo-grid-column>
            </kendo-grid>
            `
})

export class AppComponent {
    public sort: SortDescriptor[] = [{ dir: "asc", field: "ProductID" }];

    private gridDataResult: GridDataResult;

    public products: any[] = [{
        "ProductID": 1,
        "ProductName": "Chai",
        "UnitPrice": 18.0000,
        "Discontinued": true,
    }, {
        "ProductID": 2,
        "ProductName": "Chang",
        "UnitPrice": 19.0000,
        "Discontinued": false,
    }
    ];

    protected sortChange(sort: SortDescriptor[]): void {
       this.sort = sort;
       this.gridDataResult = {
            data: orderBy(this.products, this.sort),
            total: this.products.length
        };
    }

    public selectedRowChange(selectionEvent: SelectionEvent) {
        let selectedItem = this.gridDataResult.data[selectionEvent.index];
        console.log(selectedItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: when I select multiple rows with CTRL then the selectedRows only contains the last selected element. But with SHIFT, it works fine. I need to select with CTRL and get the number of selected items.

Answer (score 1):

**Just addition to original answer which is still true except one change in plunker**

It should say **this.gridView.data[e.index]**

If someone else comes to this page, can get the latest information.